# Twilio - Play/Say to both Enqueue and Queue before bridge

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I've been looking for examples where I can play an Audio to both the Enqueue and the Queue before the bridge is made.

When a user picks up from the Queue side, I'd like both sides to receive the audio "This call is being recorded," then connect the bridge.

I see where we can play an audio to the Queue side and even look for a human response so the bridge isn't connected to an answer machine.  And I can see where I can pipe in hold music.  But I can't find or think of a way to due this.

Any Ideas?